# can we use informatica power center to load into teradata cloud?

Tags: cloud, teradata, informatica, informatica-powercenter

Currently we are using Teradata as our primary database. We are doing a POC in teradata cloud.
In our current interface setup we are using Informatica power center to load data into teradata , So can we use informatica power center to load data into teradata cloud as well.

We found that all teradata utilities work in teradata cloud as well. Just want to know whether informatica power cen be used or not to load data into teradata cloud.

Comment: Hi - so what do the Informatica documentation say about this when you read it?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What are the issues?

Comment: Will it work? Probably. Is it consistent with Informatica license terms? Probably not. If there are issues, will Informatica provide support? Unlikely.

Comment: Technically when accessing a Teradata there is no difference between Cloud or onPrem. But Informatica differs between onPrem/Cloud in their support/license. If you only own a PowerCenter license there is a high chance that Informatica don't support connections to Teradata Cloud. 
How will Informatica find out whether the Teradata is onPrem or Cloud? - I have no clue.

Comment: Hello everyone,, Informatica Power center is working with teradata cloud as well.
I am able to load date from file to TD cloud using informatic power center.
We just need to give TD cloud connection details instead of TD on prem TDPID.
TD cloud connection detail is just a cloud IP address.